# How to use properties with values of a type that is a registered GType, but not a GObject?

Tags: gobject

I want to define properties on a custom GObject-based class with the type of the property being `GstStructure *`. This is a registered GType, but not a subclass of GObject. Properties are set and retrieved as `GValue`, but GValue doesn't seem to support `GType` values. It is possible to create a `g_param_spec_gtype`, but the GType parameter to that factory function is called `is_a_type`, which is confusing, because it implies boolean, so I'm not sure what this type of param spec is for. Should I just register it as a pointer and sacrifice some type-safety for simplicity, or are you supposed to use GBoxed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GParamSpec` for `GType` is for storing an actual `GType` value, not for storing instances of a type registered in the type system.

There are no `GParamSpec` provided by GLib for fundamental instantiatable types—i.e. types that inherits from `GTypeInstance` but do not derive from `GObject`—because GLib can't know anything about them: they are a separate hierarchy.

If a library is providing you with a fundamental instantiatable type, then the same library should also provide you with:

- `GValue` wrappers, for boxing and unboxing instances in properties and signals
- a `GParamSpec` type and an API to define GObject properties

The `GstStructure` type, though, is a reference counted plain old data type, and it inherits from `GBoxed`; this means you can use [`g_param_spec_boxed()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/2.62/gobject-Standard-Parameter-and-Value-Types.html#g-param-spec-boxed) to define a property that holds a `GstStructure` instance.